# How can I fix this area?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, gradient

I have just made this in illustrator. I made a path and used gradient across the stroke, but this highlighted area appeared. So, how can I fix it using **photoshop** or **illustrator** ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fiddly try, but it doesn't look so bad:

1) I copied the horizontal path protruding to the left. You need to know the height of the path (which you can calculate based on the stroke size). Create a rectangle of the same height.

2) Change the width of the rectangle in half.

3) Apply the same gradient to the **fill**, and clear the outline stroke to 0pt. Use "Linear" and an angle of 90 degrees.

4) Alter the path of the rectangle into a triangle, where the tip would be pointing to the right, down.

5) Copy said triangle, mirror it vertically.

6) Play with the width (50% should do).

[image: Steps in Illustrator]

Then adjust your horizontal path in your initial picture, so that it does not overlap with the bow, and take your triangle to cover it. Makes even a nice 3D effect.

Here's a detail of the triangles overlapping the paths, with a black outline:

[image: Detail]

A detailed view of the "fiddly joint":

[image]

This is a possible final view:

[image: Final]

By changing the right side of the triangle into curves, you may make it even look better and more "3d-ish".